# Module: See Last Modified Articles And Submitted Articles

Tags: 7

I would like to be able to see who did what and what articles were submitted, possibly on the admin dashboard - is there any module that you would recommend?

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is pretty much available by default.  If there's specific changes you need, you should create a View that matches what you need.